# Possible for bacteria to burst container?

Tags: forces, conservation-laws

This is kind of a thought experiment, but are there any conditions under which bacteria could multiply enough to burst the container they're in?

Thoughts so far: Bacteria often need oxygen to multiply, but I believe not always? They need a food source, but perhaps despite that mass already being present they might still have a larger overall volume afterwards?

For the sake of this question, I'd like to be fairly loose with the word "container", i.e. not necessarily something solid glass or even solid for that matter, but at least closed. Perhaps I could have bacteria in a bubble and they could burst that?

Thanks for indulging!

Comment: Hi John, welcome to PSE. I don't personally think this is a  physics concept, and it may be well be closed on those grounds. But rather than think of the bacteria themselves, think of the gas they produce, (and in human cases, the resultant indigestion:) , which could easily burst a bubble.

Comment: This seems to be a thought experiment. If total volume of all the bacteria keeps increasing then something must give, right?

Comment: @Countto10 I thought that possible but not sure exactly where it might fit as it's a bit of an odd question, so from a materials, density, forces, etc. point of view thought there may be a place for it here.

Comment: @Deep one of the things that gives would definitely be the food supply though, as well as potentially things like spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, bacteria can and do explode containers. Case in point: cans of Swedish [surströmming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surstr%C3%B6mming). This is fermented herring, a foul-smelling food-to-scare-foreigners-with. When left long enough the continued fermentation releases gas, which increases the pressure in the can. This sometimes leads to the can bursting. [A recent case involved a forgotten can lodged between a beam and a roof, raising the roof by two inches](https://www.thelocal.se/20140210/swedish-expert-called-to-disarm-norway-fermented-herring-stink-bomb). While there are plentiful stories about exploding cans, in reality bursting tends to be more sedate and just involve foul-smelling contents spurting out. Of course, [if the can is heated by a fire it can explode because of overpressure](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-27258303), but here it is an external thermal source doing the work, not the bacteria.

The original question was about bacterial multiplying enough to burst a container. This is less likely. The reason is that the density of bacterial typically is $\approx 1$ g/cm$^3$ like most bacterial food, so if the bacteria convert the food to more bacteria there is no change in overall volume. In the surströmming case the gas released has a far lower density, so it tries to expand the volume but is resisted by the container, producing a higher pressure. In theory there might be bacterial food that is high density enough that the conversion of it to bacteria might similarly lower the density to produce higher pressure. Sugar has density 1.59 g/cm$^3$ and yeast cells has density 1.1029, so converting pure sugar into yeast would increase the volume by 44%, which might break a weak container.

Comment: The second paragraph is very much the train of thought I'm going with in thinking that bacteria would likely have similar density to their food supply thus resulting in a negligible volume change, but wondering if there could indeed by some conceivable conditions under which this could be enough. Very much for interest than for any practical purpose.

Comment: beer bottles burst all the time in the hands of home-brewers who cap them too soon, before the fermentation process has gone far enough toward completion. this involves yeast instead of bacteria but the idea is the same. Anders, thanks for the detailed description of surstroemming, det sounds thoroughly otaekt!  I'll make a point of avoiding Sverige next time I'm in Danmark!